# Validation of dynamic # of fields with two stages of validation

Tags: javascript, validation, dynamic

I am trying to create an inventory system.  This inventory system is based off of bar codes that are MAC addresses (12 character, hexadecimal).  So on one page, I ask for the model number and how many the user wants to add, this can be anywhere from 2 to 100, based on what they enter there, they are presented with the appropriate number of MAC address fields on the next page.  What I'm trying to do is make it A) Move to the next MAC field when 12 characters are entered and B) Validate that the string entered is a 12 character hexadecimal string.  This way, someone can just scan each bar code and fluidly move through the process.  The problem that I'm having is that it's just flat out not working.  I'm thinking it's the attempt to call the dynamic input fields.

The Javascript:

```
function isValidMacAddress(mac) {
var RegExPattern = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;

if (!(mac.match(RegExPattern)) || mac.length != 12) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}

function valandmove() {
    var field = this.value+1;
    isValidMacAddress(this.value);
    if (this.value.length == 12) this.form.elements.field.focus();
}
```

The PHP/HTML:

```
if($_POST['type'] == "rad") {
    echo '<div class="cell">Model</div><div class="cell">' . $label . '</div><br />';
    for($i=1;$i<=$quan;$i++) {
        echo '<div class="cell">' . $model . '</div><div class="cell"><input type="text" name="mac' . $i . '" maxlength=12 size=14 onKeyUp="valandmove()" /></div><br />';
    }
```

Any hints?

Comment: where is "mac" in your first method... is it an argument to isValidMacAddress?

Comment: and if they are "scanning"... I don't think the onKeyUp will fire since a key isn't really being hit? what if you try on change?

Comment: As you can tell, I'm fairly new to JS.  Using 'mac' I don't think will work since the fields are dynamic, should I use 'this'?  onKeyUp worked when the if (this.value.length == 12) this.form.elements.field.focus(); was embedded directly in the HTML and not in the function.

Comment: you need to pass something into isValidMacAddress... inside valandmove change isValidMacAddress() to isValidMacAddress(this.value)... and add an argument mac to the definition of isValidMacAddress.. this should make it work, but I would think abuot the architecture a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Change isValidMacAddress to :

```
function isValidMacAddress(mac) {
    var RegExPattern = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;

    if ((mac.match(RegExPattern)) && mac.length == 12) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Change valandmove to:

```
function valandmove(input, index) {
var field = input;
if (isValidMacAddress(field.value)) field.form[index+1].focus();
 }
```

Change  to :

```
<input type="text" name="mac' . $i . '" maxlength=12 size=14 onKeyUp="valandmove(this, ' . $i .')" />
```

Comment: I've made this change and it didn't work.  Firebug is telling me that mac is undefined.

Comment: that's because I don't think "this" is valid... inside of valandmove you'll get an event object... so... I'll edit the above...

Comment: This is assuming all of your inputs in that form are just text boxes... when it gets to the end of the text boxes it's focus what I assume is some sort of submit button

Comment: Ok, yes you are correct that there will eventually be a submit button on the bottom of the page and no other inputs.  I've implemented your code and am working through the issues.  It was skipping over a field, so I took out the +1 and just left index, then instead of the the isValidMacAddress kicking back false, it throws an error alert.  Now the problem is that anything I type in there throws that it's an invalid MAC address...

Comment: I've changed the code around, now it's:  function isValidMacAddress(mac) {
    var RegExPattern = '^[a-fA-F0-9]+$';

    if (mac.match(RegExPattern)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return alert("Invalid MAC");
    }
}

function valandmove(input, index) {
 var field = input;
 if (input.length == 12) {
  if (isValidMacAddress(input)) {
   field.form[index].focus();
  }
 }
} Which I can format properly if desired above.  Now I'm getting that field.form is undefined.

Comment: ok... that just means you can't get the form from the field... it also means your code is working properly... you'll have to find a way to get the form from it's field (input box)